Moved Kafka Connect standalone connectors from EC2 to ECS and getting timeout crashes
Moved working standalone Kafka connect connectors hosted on a single ec2 machine to dockerized ECS services and they run for a few minutes then have timeout crashes. Full crash below ->
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:27,516] INFO
> Herder stopped
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:122)
> kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:27,516] INFO Kafka
> Connect stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:72)
> kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:27,515] ERROR
> Executor java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@413cc5d9[Shutting
> down, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed
> tasks = 1] did not terminate in time
> (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ThreadUtils:80) kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,514] INFO
> Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:703)
> kafka-connect

> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,514] INFO App
> info kafka.connect for 10.2.0.87:8083 unregistered
> (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83) kafka-connect

> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,514] INFO
> Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:268)
> kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,513] INFO
> Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:71)
> kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,513] INFO
> Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:693)
> kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,513] INFO
> Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
> (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:697) kafka-connect

> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,511] ERROR
> [Connector|worker] Connector 'SourceConnector' failed to properly shut
> down, has become unresponsive, and may be consuming external
> resources. Correct the configuration for this connector or remove the
> connector. After fixing the connector, it may be necessary to restart
> this worker to release any consumed resources.
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:448) kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:25,512] INFO
> Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:247)
> kafka-connect

> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,516] INFO
> [Connector|task-0] App info kafka.producer for
> connector-producer-SourceConnector-0 unregistered
> (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83) kafka-connect

> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,515] INFO
> [Connector|task-0] Metrics scheduler closed
> (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:693) kafka-connect

> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,515] INFO
> [eConnector|task-0] Closing reporter
> org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
> (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:697) kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,515] INFO
> [Connector|task-0] Metrics reporters closed
> (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:703)
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,511] INFO
> [SourceConnector|worker] Stopping connector SourceConnector
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:419) kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,511] INFO
> [SourceConnector|worker] Scheduled shutdown for
> WorkerConnector{id=SourceConnector}
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:267)    kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,511] INFO
> [SourceConnector|worker] Stopping com.shepherd.HttpSourceConnector
> (com.shepherd.HttpSourceConnector:54) kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:20,506] ERROR
> [SourceConnector|task-0] Graceful stop of task SourceConnector-0
> failed. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:1035)    kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,505] INFO REST
> server stopped
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:365)    kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,505] INFO
> Herder stopping
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:111)    kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,505] INFO
> [SourceConnector|task-0] Stopping task SourceConnector-0
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:1008)    kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,503] INFO
> Stopped http_8083@7f0952cf{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083}
> (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:383)  kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,503] INFO node0
> Stopped scavenging
> (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:149)    kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,499] INFO Kafka
> Connect stopping
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:67) kafka-connect
> 
> June 06, 2024 at 11:39 (UTC-6:00) [2024-06-06 17:39:15,500] INFO
> Stopping REST server
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:348)

All standalone connectors when ran via ./connect-standalone.sh (9 or so at a single time) ran fine with no crashes for >5 days at a time. Moved the connector code to a single docker container and now I have ~9 separate ECS services running one standalone connector each, they poll() a few times then crash with the error message above.
